# stop AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have two view controllers:

MainMenuView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BackgroundSound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    play =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    play.delegate=self;
    [play play];
}
```

and PlayAreaView:

```
- (void)counttimer
{
    ///here is my code for NSTimer, if Timer is 0, Automatically I go to GameOver viewController
    MainMenuView *vv = [[MainMenu alloc]init];
    [vv.play stop];
    GameOver *gv = [[GameOver alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:gv animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Before I go to GameOver, or when I'm already on game over view, I want to stop `AVAudioPlayer` from my `MainMenuView`. help please. I tried to alloc `MainMenuView`, and to use `[MainMenu.play stop]`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Does PlayAreaView comes before MainMenuView or opposite of it?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should name your variables a little differently.  Seeing "`[play play]`" in code is really *strange*.

Secondly, when I look at your "`counttimer`" method, what I see is you creating your "`MainMenuView`" view controller via "`alloc`" & "`init`", and promptly stopping the player even before the view is loaded.

If you want to stop the player, make certain your "`AVAudioPlayer`" object is actually loaded.

So in your code, do something like this:

```
if (vv.play)
    [vv.play stop];
else
    NSLog( @"vv.play is NULL, it doesn't exist yet");
```

That should help you to track down where the appropriate place to call "`stop`" would be.